# rsync --exclude not excluding first value

Tags: rsync

When I use rsync `--exclude`, like so:

```
rsync -avzhe --exclude={'/var/','/generated/','/app/etc/env.php'} --dry-run /home/site/ /home/site2/
```

...the directory `/var/` is not excluded.

However, if I do something like this:

```
rsync -avzhe --exclude={'/ignore/','/var/','/generated/','/app/etc/env.php'} --dry-run /home/site/ /home/site2/
```

Everything works as expected, except the `/ignore/` directory is fake. It seems that when using the `exclude={}` syntax, the first value is ignored.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything here that'd cause this problem. Try putting `set -x` before it, and see what bash thinks the bracket expression expands to. Note that the output from `set -x` sometimes uses unexpected quoting/escaping styles; in this case, I'd expect it to just leave the single-quotes off because they're not actually needed, but if it does use quotes in the output... that probably indicates there's something weird in there.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is:

```
rsync -avzhe --exclude={'/var/','/generated/','/app/etc/env.php'} [...]
```

The `{}` is bash-syntax. After expansion, the commandline becomes:

```
rsync -avzhe --exclude=/var/ --exclude=/generated/ [...]
```

Expanding the `rsync` options gives:

```
rsync -a -v -z -h -e --exclude=/var/ --exclude=/generated/ [...]
```

The `rsync` option `-e` is defined as:

```
-e, --rsh=COMMAND           specify the remote shell to use
```

From this we can see that the first argument after the `-e` is used as `COMMAND` (instead of being treated as an exclude rule). You are performing a local copy, so this option/argument pair is unused. Had you been performing a remote copy, you would have seen an error like: `rsync: Failed to exec --exclude=/var/`

The solution is to either specify a `COMMAND` for `-e` or not to use it.